# js conditional test for utf string of special character

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, utf

Say I have a div with innerHTML set using the HTML code for a rocket: `&#128640;`

How do I do a conditional test for that character in javascript?

E.g. how do I get below to log "rocket"

```js
let rocket = document.getElementById("rocket")

if (rocket.innerHTML == "&#128640;") console.log("rocket") 
else console.log("no rocket");
```

```html
<div id="rocket">
&#128640;
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using `charCodeAt(0)` to get the unicode character code of the rocket and got `55357` as the result and the code below works.

```js
let rocket = document.getElementById("rocket").innerText

if (rocket.charCodeAt(0) == 55357) console.log("rocket") 
else console.log("no rocket");
```

```html
<div id="rocket">
&#128640;
</div>
```

Hope this helps until a better answer comes. You can use `console.log()` to check the character code if you want to have a different item instead of a rocket.

Answer (score 1):

I could achieve this way. Note that I've used ".innerText"

```js
var ic = '';
var r = document.getElementById("rocket");

if (r.innerText == ic) console.log("rocket"); 
else console.log("no rocket");
```

```html
<div id="rocket">
&#128640;
</div>
```

Comment: says `no rocket` on my browser

Comment: I've tested with Chrome, Firefox & Edge. Which browser are you using pilchard?

Comment: Safari on desktop. Looks like it's due to your missing closing on the div